# Select element inside selected tab to populate content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have a dynamic jQuery function where i add jquery tabs dynamically. It produces HTML like below

```
<div id="chattabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="some_7"><a href="#ui-tabs-2"><span>Tsefolasha Sefolasha</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" id="some_9"><a href="#ui-tabs-4"><span>Emaynor Maynor</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
        <ul id="messagelist_7">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <ul id="messagelist_9">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="text" value=" " id="msg">
    <input type="button" value="send" id="send">
    <div id="ui-tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    <div id="ui-tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to add content to each of the tabs when the users clicks the button send at the bottom . something like

```
$('#message_9').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
```

How can I do that?

Also, how can I get this id from outside of `chattabs` div?

Comment: So the user clicks send and you need to add content to every single tab you have?  Are you adding the same content on every tab?  Or is there some sort of relationship between the tab and the content that the tab will show?

Comment: i just need to add it to the selected tab

Comment: Do selected tabs have a special class?

Comment: i know the Li has a sepical class but not the div where the ui sits as far as i know. this is a standard jquery tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the activate event when you initialize your tabs.

```
$( "#chattabs" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {

        //Append something to the active tab
        ui.newPanel.append();

        //Get the active tab`s nested ul
        var ul = ui.newPanel.find('ul');

        //Get the id of the active tab's nested ul
        var ul_id = ul.attr('id');


    }
});
```

Comment: that' was not what i was looking for . i need to extarct that id in li or ui element for selected tab so i can post the message to proper tabs and notify server about it as well that this id has been updated

Comment: Can you provide an example scenario as I do not know which id you are talking about.

Comment: from the above htl, i need <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" id="some_9"> some_9 since this is the active li in the tab

Comment: `$('.ui-state-active').attr('id');`